# To reduce gap between tableview section in swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I want to reduce gap between tableview section in swift. I tried “.leastNormalMagnitude”. But still I am getting some space between the sections. I want there should be no space. Can anyone help me?

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            return UIView()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return 0
```

instead of

```
return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
```

Comment: it is working fine when tableview style is "Plain" .  But for  "Grouped" tableview style it is not woking good. still some spaces are there

Answer (score 0):

To hide a section header:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return .zero
}
```